# Angular return observable from stomp service

Tags: angular, stomp

For the unsubscribe reason (disconnect watch topic) I must use the subscriber on stomp service. Also need return Observable (because I use it in ngrx effect).

But I can't find solution:

```
  public getUserInfoNotification(userID: number): Observable<User> {

    this.stompSub = this.stompService.watch(`${WEBSOCKET_PATH}/${userID}`).subscribe(items => {
      of(JSON.parse(items.body));
    });
    return EMPTY;
  }
```

It is not the proper solution, one time will emmit EMPTY message, and no send the next one.

Comment: Why the empty `pipe()`?

Comment: Sorry, for debugging issue, was there tap(console.log). Not important in this case.

Comment: This method is returning an Observable, but this `EMPTY` value is being returned. Why not subscribe to this service as part of the component initialization, then update a member variable with the notification content? If you need some side effects to the notification, use a setter to perform that work while updating member variables for persistence.

Comment: For the architectural reasons, I must create it in service and collect the response in ngrx effect.